# C++ - Creating Makefile on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, g++, mingw

I have a project that make some processing on circular double linked List. I must use this project files in different directories and I made this project but I couldn't create a Makefile for Windows.

My success commands that I use on Command Prompt as shown below;

```
g++ -c src\Demo.cpp -o lib\Demo.o
g++ -c src\CircularDoubleLinkedListProcessor.cpp -o lib\CircularDoubleLinkedListProcessor.o
g++ -c src\CircularDoubleLinkedList.cpp -o lib\CircularDoubleLinkedList.o

g++ lib\Demo.o lib\CircularDoubleLinkedListProcessor.o lib\CircularDoubleLinkedList.o -o bin\Demo.exe

.\bin\Demo.exe
```

Also, this project's class diagram:

> Demo -> CircularDoubleLinkedListProcessor -> CircularDoubleLinkedList -> DoubleLinkedListNode

**File Hierarchy**:

[image]

I would be very grateful, if you could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, we can easily use it similar to the Linux environment. I was confused looking at some samples.

**makefile**

```
ALL:
    g++ -c src\Demo.cpp -o lib\Demo.o
    g++ -c src\CircularDoubleLinkedListProcessor.cpp -o lib\CircularDoubleLinkedListProcessor.o
    g++ -c src\CircularDoubleLinkedList.cpp -o lib\CircularDoubleLinkedList.o

    g++ lib\Demo.o lib\CircularDoubleLinkedListProcessor.o lib\CircularDoubleLinkedList.o -o bin\Demo.exe

    .\bin\Demo.exe
```

**Command:**

```
> mingw32-make
```